# How to find this element in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

The HTML is:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px;">
<input class="v-textfield v-textfield-InputTextFieldStyle 
InputTextFieldStyle v-textfield-focus" type="text" style="width: 56em;" 
maxlength="160"/>
</div>
```

The XPath of the required text field is coming as:

```
.//*[@id='inputLayout']/div/div[1]/div[2]/input
```

Absolute XPath:

```
html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/input
```

However Selenium gives `NoSuchElementException`. How to find this text field element in Selenium?

Comment: Given HTML doesn't contain any element with an ID attribute...

Comment: No id or name tag have been used

Comment: try `//input[@class='v-textfield v-textfield-InputTextFieldStyle 
InputTextFieldStyle v-textfield-focus']` and let me know

Comment: Dosen't work either with class name. Gives Compound class names not permitted

Comment: @Chirag Gupta, don't use Class Selector for that use `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='v-textfield v-textfield-InputTextFieldStyle InputTextFieldStyle v-textfield-focus']"))` Let me know if any concern in this

Comment: @NarendraR that too dosen't work. No such Element

Comment: @ChiragGupta, Can you add the site URL or add some more HTML code. so we can rectify the issue

Comment: add some wait before finding it

Comment: @Murthi Thanks Man, waiting worked!

Comment: @ChiragGupta, did you try my answer? If it was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following CSS selector:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".v-textfield.v-textfield-InputTextFieldStyle.InputTextFieldStyle.v-textfield-focus")));
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: No Such Element Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".v-textfield.v-textfield-InputTextFieldStyle.InputTextFieldStyle.v-textfield-focus"}

Answer (score 0):

```
p=driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/input")
p.text
```

Try the above code and let me know if you need any help